# Attempting to run Images through a Loop Displaying Each in turn (Dice Roll). QuerySelector Failing

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

### Assignment

I am a software development student and have been tasked with a dice game assignment. I wanted to add simulate a die roll by looping through and array, displaying each image (die faces 1 - 5) in turn.

### Problems I am Facing

When I call this function the die doesn't act any differently than usual. I am getting errors in the console stating that 'animate' is null. Leading me to the conclusion that the issue lies in the querySelector which also returns null.

```
Error: "dice.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML'
of null
    at imageLoop (dice.js:18)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (dice.js:62)"
```

### What I have tried

My first approach to the problem was staring at my screen intensely, to the dulcet tones of Pink Floyd. Hours later, when my eyes started to hurt, I attempted a different syntax, not knowing the code above wasn't returning. Since diagnosing the problem through the console, I have check over all of my code looking for the issue, but I can't find it.

Here's the code snippet of what I had on line 18. I have a strong feeling I am barking up the wrong tree but I can't think of anything else to do

```html
animate.innerHTML += '<img src=\"'+imgArr[i]+'\">';
```

I have also tried the medium of expressive dance, toe stretches and gazing to the skies with inspirational music playing; not unlike they do in the movies.

### What I Need

Being a student, I really need to understand what has gone wrong as opposed to direct answers with no explanation.

### My Code

This is my first post, so I apologise if I have the formatting wrong. Please let me know if there's anything I can improve on.

```js
function imageLoop (){
    let img1 = document.getElementById('die1');
    let img2 = document.getElementById('die2');
    let img3 = document.getElementById('die3');
    let img4 = document.getElementById('die4');
    let img5 = document.getElementById('die5');
    let img6 = document.getElementById('die6');
// declare array
let imgArr = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6'];
// do something with it

// problematic code below
    i=0;
    while(i < 10){
      let windowRoll = document.getElementById('windowDie');
      let animate = windowRoll.querySelector('p');
      console.log(animate);
      animate.innerHTML = imgArr[i];
      console.log(i);
      i++;
    }
}
// problematic code above
function roll(){
    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) +1;
    let box = document.getElementById("windowDie");
    console.log(x);
    document.getElementById('rollSound').pause();
    document.getElementById('rollSound').currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById('rollSound').play();
    
    
    if(x === 1){
      let target =  box.querySelector('p');
      box.innerHTML = `<img src="images/die1.png"> `;
    }
    else if(x === 2){
      let target =  box.querySelector('p');
      box.innerHTML = `<img src="/images/die2.png"> `;
    }
    else if(x === 3){
      let target =  box.querySelector('p');
      box.innerHTML = `<img src="/images/die3.png"> `;
    }
    else if(x === 4){
      let target =  box.querySelector('p');
      box.innerHTML = `<img src="/images/die4.png"> `;
    }
    else if(x === 5){
      let target =  box.querySelector('p');
      box.innerHTML = `<img src="/images/die5.png"> `;
    }
    else if(x === 6){
      let target =  box.querySelector('p');
      box.innerHTML = `<img src="/images/die6.png"> `;
    }
    
    return x;}
let submit = document.getElementById('submit');
submit.addEventListener("click", () =>{
    roll();
    imageLoop();
})
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}
body{
    background-image: url('/images/bg.jpg');
    }
.header{
    padding: 3vh 6vh 1vh 6vh;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: rgba(228, 15, 15, 0.514);
    color:wheat;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.options{  
    display: flex;
   
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    min-width: 30vw;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 1vh 1vh 5vh 1vh;
    border-right: black 1vh;
    }
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.left-container{
    width: 30vw;
    height: 30vw;
}
.right-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 40vw;
    height: 40vw;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: 5vh;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.playerOne{
    min-width: 40%;
    min-height: 50%;
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 1vh 1vh 1vh 1vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(71, 6, 50, 0.767);
    text-decoration: white underline;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    
}
.playerTwo{
    min-width: 40%;
    min-height: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(71, 6, 50, 0.767);
    border-radius: 1vh 1vh 1vh 1vh;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 1vh;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    
}
.window{
    height: 30vh;
    width: auto;
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 1vh 1vh 1vh 1vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    object-fit: cover;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(71, 6, 50, 0.767);
    text-decoration: white underline;
    padding-top: 1vh;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    display: flex;
    
}
img{
    max-width: 90%; 
    max-height: 90%;
}

.box{
    background-color:rgba(228, 15, 15, 0.404);
    margin-top: 5vh;
    color:wheat;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    padding:1vh 2vh 2vh 2vh;
    margin-left: 5vh;
    margin-right: 5vh;
    max-height: 60vh;
    margin-bottom: 5vh;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: white underline;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.459) 2vh 2vh;
}
.middle-container{
    height: 40vh;
    width: 40vh;
    color:wheat;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 8, 8, 0.658) 1vh 1vh 0;
}
.button{
  margin-top: 10vh;
  min-width: 20vw;
  min-height: 10vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(purple, black);
  border-radius: 2vh 2vh 2vh 2vh;
  border-style: groove;
  color: wheat;
  font-size: large;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527) 2vh 2vh;
}
.button:active{
    background-image: linear-gradient(yellow, black);
}
.imgLoopImages{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
    <title>Dice Game</title>
</head>
<div class="header">
    <h1>Dice Game - Code Nation</h1>
    <div class="options">
        <div class="headOption">About</div>
        <div class="headOption">Contact</div>
        <div class="headOption">How to Play</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box left-container">
        <h2>How to Play</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="box middle-container" id="show">
        
        <h2>Dice Window</h2>
        
        <div class="window" id ="windowDie"></div>
        <div>
            <button type="button" id="submit" class="button">Roll</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="box right-container">
        <div class="playerOne">Player One</div>
        <div class="playerTwo">Player Two</div>
        
    </div>

</div>

<div class="imgLoopImages">
<image src="/images/die1.png" id="die1"></image>
<image src="/images/die2.png" id="die2"></image>
<image src="/images/die3.png" id="die3"></image>
<image src="/images/die4.png" id="die4"></image>
<image src="/images/die5.png" id="die5"></image>
<image src="/images/die6.png" id="die6"></image>
</div>
<audio src="/sounds/die.wav" id="rollSound"></audio>
<script src="/scripts/dice.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is simple. In this part of your code :

```js
while(i < 10){
      let windowRoll = document.getElementById('windowDie');
      let animate = windowRoll.querySelector('p');
      console.log(animate);
      animate.innerHTML = imgArr[i];
      console.log(i);
      i++;
    }
```

You first select the element with the id "windowDie", and then try to select one paragraphe in it with `windowRoll.querySelector('p')`. But in your html code, I don't see any `<p> </p>` tag inside the element which id is `"windowDie"`. Try adding `<p> </p>` inside the `div` which id is `windowDie`, like that :`<div class="window" id ="windowDie"><p> </p></div>`.

---

In case you don't know, `querySelector()` allows you to select htmlElements more easily than the methods `getElementBy...` do. You can see how it works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Comment: Hi Jean, thanks a lot for the answer. I have had those tags there at various stages but never realised I hadn't put them back. I just replaced them and sadly it's the same situation.

Comment: Please is it again the variable animate which is undefined?